# Consulta de Total Geral

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum

Estou com a necessidade de construção de uma query onde tenho a seguinte situação

Tabela 1- Vendas

```
 [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GOO7.png
```

Nessa tabela que tenho outros códigos de vendedores com outros valores.
Eu estou tentando trazer uma nova coluna onde eu traga a soma de todas as vendas daquele mês, sem levar em consideração o filtro de vendedor que aplico no WHERE.

Eu tentei usar o sum(over paritition) porém ele me trouxe o valor total do mes considerando o filtro do vendedor.

Eu preciso apenas da ajuda de como fazer com que esse VENDAS_T não leve em consideração o filtro de COD_Vend, mas sim, o ANO e MES da linha

```
DECLARE 
@Cod_Vend int,@Data date SET @Cod_Vend=9 SET    @Data = getdate()

SELECT 
    LTRIM(RTRIM(t.APELIDO)) AS 'VENDEDOR',
    ad.ANO, 
    ad.MES, 
    CONCAT(ad.ANO,'/',ad.MES) DATA,
    SUM(ad.VENDA) VENDA_I, 
    SUM(SUM (ad.VENDA)) OVER (partition by ad.MES ORDER BY ad.MES) AS Vendas_T,
    SUM(ad.DEVOLUCAO) DEVOLUCAO_I
FROM sankhya.ANALISE_DEVOLUCAO2 ad
JOIN sankhya.TGFVEN t ON ad.COD_VENDEDOR=t.CODVEND
WHERE ad.COD_VENDEDOR=@Cod_Vend
AND t.ATIVO='S'
AND ad.ANO=year(@Data)
AND ad.MES >=month(@Data)-6
GROUP BY 
    t.APELIDO,
    ad.ANO, 
    ad.MES`insira o código aqui
```

`

Comment: E por que você não faz a `query` pra pegar o total, guarda em uma variável e só mostra em uma coluna na nova `query`?

Comment: Pois é @Sorack eu pensei nisso nessa madrugada do nada...eu tava querendo complicar algo simples... Eu só fiz uma subselect agregando os valores como eu queria e coloquei ela num join.